# How can I use the wither to make a wood farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I’ve been playing on this server and I’ve been thinking about making a wood farm. However, the server has a no duplication rule. They do have a claims plug-in and I can turn mob griefing off and on in each claim, so I was thinking I could use a wither and trap him in a mob griefing 'off' cage so he can’t escape, but then make him shoot at the wood that’s being made. I couldn’t think of any solutions so if anyone knows how to do this let me know.

Comment: I don’t understand what the problem is. It seems like you have a viable way to make a wood farm

Comment: Maybe you could have the wither on the edge of a claim, bordering another? Unless you can toggle exactly what spots of a claim can and can't be broken. It may help if you provided the server so we know the exact rules of how it worked.